# A "goto unexpected" error keeps showing and I cannot find why

Tags: batch-file, goto

```
echo Decode this next puzzle:
echo ymnx nx f kzs lfrj
echo Hint: The shift cipher is 5
set /p b=Answer: 
if %b%==%Answer: this is a fun game% goto correct2
if %b%==%?% goto oops
:correct2
echo hello!
pause
```

I keep getting a goto unexpected error and I have checked several forums and cannot find the problem

Comment: You don't have an `oops` label.

Comment: Oops, sorry, its in another part

Answer (score 0):

Conventional `IF` syntax is `if [not] operand1==operand2 somethingtodo` where operand1 and operand2 are both strings. If the strings contain separators like <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or other characters that have a special meaning to batch then the string must be `"enclosed in quotes"`.

SET /P "var=Prompt" does not change `var` if <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone is pressed. Consequently, if `var` is originally empty, it remains empty.

If you code `if %var%==somevalue goto somewhere` then if `var` is empty, this is resolved to `if ==somevalue goto somewhere`. "quoting the arguments" thus: `if "%var%"=="somevalue" goto somewhere` alleviates the situation.

---

```
if %b%==%Answer: this is a fun game% goto correct2
if %b%==%?% goto oops
```

should be

```
if "%b%"=="Answer: this is a fun game" goto correct2
if "%b%"=="?" goto oops
```

(Note that I've also corrected a second error: `%b%` will access the *value* of variable `b`. In your code, `%Answer: this is a fun game%` would attempt to access the *value* of the variable `Answer: this is a fun game` not the literal string `Answer: this is a fun game`)

(I'll leave you to figure out that the correct string to match against is "this is a fun game" not "Answer: this is a fun game")

Further hint: After you've made these two changes, you need to consider what happens if you were to enter something other than `?` or `this is a fun game`. Batch would simply proceed to the next instruction after that second `if` - `:correct2` is simply a marker, batch only uses it as a destination for `goto` or `call` - so the next instruction is the `echo hello!`

Comment: Can you put that more simply

Answer (score 0):

Try these two lines: spaces break things and are most often handled with double quotes.
The double quotes also protect the statements from characters like `& < > |` etc

```
if /i "%b%"=="this is a fun game" goto correct2
if /i "%b%"=="?" goto oops
```